# How to generate automatic Rspec tests for existing scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have an application on Ruby on Rails. All files have been modified from what the scaffold by itself generates. I want to include automatic testing with the Rspec gem, but I want it to generate all the automatic tests it normally does (since this is my first time working with rspec).

I have seen that the usual way to do it is to install Rspec before generating the scaffolds (and when you generate the scaffold the tests are automatically generated), but since everything is already generated, how can I generate the tests only?

I have got all the way to the `rails generate rspec:install` command, getting it ready for the test runs.

How can I automatically generate the tests for an existing scaffold?

Comment: I'm not a frecuent user... I don't even know how the points work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generators will prompt before overwriting any existing files. Just add RSpec and re-run the generator(s), skipping any files you want to keep.

If you are paranoid (and why shouldn't you be?), commit your work first.

Comment: since the `generate scaffold` command asks for all the attributes belonging to a model, I should write them all as they exist in the model when running the command, right?

Comment: No, just skip the model. You only want to create the spec (test) files, skip everything else.

Answer (score 6):

```
rails g rspec:scaffold scaffold_name
```

where `scaffold_name` is the name you used in the scaffold generation, in this case `rails g scaffold scaffold_name`

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Rails 6, you can add the **--skip-collision-check** and **--skip** flags to ignore the files that already exist.

The first flag permits rails to proceed with a scaffold if there is a collision. The second flag tells rails what to do when it encounters a collision. In this case, it skips the original (i.e. pass over or leave the original file alone). So after you've installed RSpec, run your original scaffold again...

```
rails g scaffold Example title:string --skip-collision-check --skip
```

and then Rails will generate whatever RSpec files you're missing (requests, routing, views, etc.)